# Google App Engine continuously starting removed version/instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-apps, gcloud

I've got a problem with incorrectly deployed Google App Engine instances - I deployed 3 instances with invalid entry point script which failed (error is raised and sent to Sentry).

The application is Ruby on Rails project and the failing part is `rails db:migrate` part.

Even when I disabled the whole application the GAE is Creating VM, then the error is raised and then is Deleting the VM. Those instances were removed from webpage console and all 3 of them are from one service.

The GAE tries to deploy them which causes usage of resources (also the IP quota etc are used so I cannot do anything tbh) and the failures are available in logs - where I can see the whole stacktrace with the prefix in form of: api[20190429t085718] ([]).

I can find a resource by searching by this timestamp - they are appearing in search results, but when I click on them the message that they are "Not found"/"Not existing" appears.

How can I delete them? Or will they be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone encounters such a problem and founds this post: problem was solved after ~6h, instances stopped deploying (so it was enough to just wait)